# Multiple schemas on multiple machines in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, cluster-computing, scalability

Scaling multiple schemas on multiple machine, I am using PostgreSQL as backend system, now I want to perform the lookup of schema that on which machine the schema resides, so like I have two machines M1 and M2 on both of the machines D1 and D2 are installed now tenant1 schema is on DB1 and Tenant2 schema is on DB2, now both the tenants will use the same application server, either in this case I have to use cluster and partition nodes and every node contain some amount of data or the like. The same application can be used by tenant1 and tenant2, now I want some solution to stay in the middle and perform lookup and caching of the pooling. Is it possible to get it done by using  Cluster ? Or I have to make a program like PgPool II that appears as Database Sever and lookup the schema for me.

Comment: If your schemas and their servers don't change often, it would likely be more efficient to have the decision about which database to connect to handled in your application on in`pgbouncer` (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) or pgpool2.

Comment: thanks bma, pgbouncer seems viable option, but these servers will be having no replication, I mean the servers will hold different data, so if tenant1 do request to pgbouncer and tenant2 would it lookup the machine on which the schema is automatically?

Comment: I cannot say for certain, but perhaps pgbouncer can be configured to direct your queries to the correct db based on some logic in the pgbouncer config.ini file. If not, you will likely have to handle that in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of two things.

1. You could use pgpool or application-level connection pooling to make the decision.
2. If you need it to be db-transparent you could set up schemas with pl/proxy procedures to handle sharding of the db out in this way.  This would allow you to have your "front-end" database servers coordinate queries for the storage shards (each in a different partition).